# Load more posts button

Tags: c#, php, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms social media project I am working on I would like to display the feed so that it displays the first 10 posts. (Posts are the posts by people you follow sorted by their timestamp and requested through a URL).

Right now I have is displaying all the posts which can range to 100s. I would like it to display 10 then when you scroll down it adds 10 more and so forth.

**I tried** adding a `$section = $_POST['sections']` and sections would equal 1-10 to start then when scrolled down it would request 11-20. Except a problem I found was if a user posts while you're scrolling down it would mess up the order since each post is now one id higher (Auto incrementing post id)

Would it be best to still gather all the posts from the URL and only display 1-10 through the C# side or should I have it done Webside in the PHP

**Another question** is how could I track when the user scrolls to the bottom of the ScrollView so right before they reach the end I can send the request

Comment: have the client send the ID of the last post, then the webservice should return the next X based on that ID

Comment: @Jason That idea sounds perfect! Except do you know how I could make a method run when the bottom of ScrollView is reached.

Comment: @Jason Also what if the poster deletes their post, Then the user scrolls, the web service wouldn't know what to do since the Id wouldn't be in the database.

Comment: then don't allow deletes, or do soft deletes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is an infinite scrolling list view.

There are a number of nuget package that provide this functionality.

[Here is a blog post providing full details on how to implement one.](http://15mgm15.ghost.io/2017/11/28/implement-an-infinite-scrolling-listview-with-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I use StackLayouts because the posts can have lots of data ranging from polls and to plain text.

Comment: Moving to a list view would give you a lot of advantages over a scroll view and stack layouts. One is allowing elements to be recycled meaning much better memory use. Another is the type of infinite scrolling extensions listed above. It doesn't matter how much data is in each post. You can use data templates if required.

Comment: Right now I'm formatting the posts by looping through each one and using this method https://pastebin.com/B1qW49Ez , I don't know if this will be supported in a list view, I never really worked with one.

Comment: Yes you can do all that sort of thing using data templates. The best approach is to use XAML, MVVM and data binding. It may be a bit of a learning curve but will lead to much more maintainable and testable apps.

Comment: Here is good starting place https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Comment: And here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating/

Comment: And this is my favourite MVVM framework https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm

Comment: I'm lost... I don't get how to implement it at all.

Comment: It's not a quick fix and its not something you can just slot in. The whole app has to be implemented as an MVVM solution. There is a learning curve involved and it may not be feasible to change your current app over to MVVM depending on your timescales. But its worth investigating and playing with for your next app.

Comment: Here are a few videos https://blog.xamarin.com/the-xamarin-show-getting-started-with-mvvm/

Comment: I tried starting without MVVM, does this look good so far? https://pastebin.com/DxyGy35U Also is it possible to set the font size in the  foreach loop so I could use stuff like; if(post.type ==1) bodySize=10 else (post.type == 2) bodySize = 20

Comment: Yes that's definitely moving the code in the right direction.You can use a value converter to set the font size based on the post type https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/data-binding/converters/

Comment: Can I add spacing between each ListView item, is there something like Margin or Padding? Margin seems to make it crash?

Comment: You should be able to add a margin to your stack layout

Comment: Is it possible to just have a StackLayout in the ListView and bind that StackLayout to one I format in C# with all the items in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164720/discussion-between-steve-chadbourne-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1):

Like what the above post said, what you're after is a infinite scroll list view.

You can either use nuget for it or create your own. If you wanted to create your own, what I did was to create a `class : behavior<ListView>`, inside the class, you bind your `Command` and `Converter` and create an `OnItemAppearing` method is where you insert where you can execute your `Command`. You also have to override `OnDetachingFrom` and `OnAttachedTo`

After you have created your `Behavior`, implement it this way on your xaml:

```
<behaviours:Infinite Command="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                     Converter="{StaticResource ItemVisibilityEventArgsConverter}">
</behaviours:Infinite>
```

During your `LoadMoreCommand` you can put your logic here if you still have items to fetch then set the visibility of your `Button` to `True`. Sorry I cannot post the whole code behind.